# How to make multiple instances of global variables in C++

Tags: c++

The question title is probably hard to understand, but here's my question in a bit more detail:

I'm new to C++, and am making a program that would be much simpler by using global variables.  (I know they're usually bad, but I'm certain any alternative is way worse.)  I know that there are many ways to make things like global variables.  My problem is that one of the features of this program is that, under certain circumstances, there can be multiple threads of (almost) the entire program going on.  Each of these threads would need their own instances of these global variables.  So, my question is, what type of thing would I have to do to make some type of global variable that I could create multiple instances of?  I don't care how it would be made.  I would prefer that all of the global variables could be known to be global in their names (something like a namespace) to prevent accidental collision of names, but this isn't necessary.

I've thought about using an instance of a class that stores all of the values, but I can't think of an easy way to make it easily accessible to all of the different files/functions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not use global variables.

Comment: Really do not. As you are new get out of that mindset

Comment: I'm not new to programming; I've been programming for several years.  I just decided to finally bite the C++ bullet recently.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use a thread local for this, each thread will have it's own instance.

```
thread_local int foo = 0;
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage#C_and_C.2B.2B

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Singleton with multiple instance functions:

```
struct GlobalVariables {
  int var1;
  int var2;
  static GlobalVariables& instance1(){
    static GlobalVariables instance;
    return instance
  }
  static GlobalVariables& instance2(){
    static GlobalVariables instance;
    return instance
  }
};

int main(){
  auto& vars1 = GlobalVariables::instance1();
  vars1.var1 = 42;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could consider using a map structure for each global variable in which the thread ID would be used as a key.

For example, if you want each thread to have it's own instance of:

```
int foo
```

then rather than creating the above global 'foo' you could create a map:

```
map<size_t, int> foo
```

and each thread would write to "it's own instance" of foo like this:

```
foo[std::this_thread::get_id().hash()] = foo_value_for_this_thread
```

and read as such:

```
foo_value_for_this_thread = foo[std::this_thread::get_id().hash()]
```